# How to render html file inside of .ejs file

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want to load a default header on a .ejs file.

I asked ChatGPT but it didnt give me the correct code.

This is the index.ejs file that is being send over email:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Web Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <% include header %>
    <h1>Welcome to My Web Page</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

ChatGPT said to use the tag `<% include header %>` but that didnt work.

These two fields are in the same folder.

The header.html file is the following:

```
<header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Is there any way to render html inside a .ejs file?

Below is the actual code that sends the email:

```
async function sendEmails(winningCampaigns) {
    fs.readFile('backend/views/index.ejs', 'utf-8', async (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        let html = data.replace(/{{name}}/g, 'John Doe');
        for (let campaign of winningCampaigns) {
            sendEmail({
            
                to: "jcasasmail@gmail.com",
                subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
                html: html
            })
        }

    });  
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For starters, there's no purpose for the `async` keyword if the function doesn't use `await`. Any code that `await`s `sendEmails` won't actually wait for `readFile` to resolve because it's callback rather than promise-based. Consider using `fs.promises.readFile` here, or better yet, use EJS's built-in `renderFile`.

On to the main point, your code doesn't run EJS at all. `fs.readFile` doesn't treat the file as a template, even with an `.ejs` extension.

`data.replace(/{{name}}/g, 'John Doe');` defeats the purpose of EJS, which should be doing the templating. You're probably in a testing phase, but `name` isn't used in the template.

You can use `<%- include("header.html") %>` in EJS to include a .html file, which should be in the same directory as the EJS template.

Here's how I'd approach the `sendEmails` function:

```js
const ejs = require("ejs"); // ^3.1.8
const path = require("path");

async function sendEmails(winningCampaigns) {
  const p = path.join("backend", "views", "index.ejs");
  const html = await ejs.renderFile(p, {name: "John Doe"});

  for (const campaign of winningCampaigns) {
    sendEmail({
      to: "<Your email address>",
      subject: "Hello ✔",
      html,
    });
  }
}
```

Note that I'm using `path.join()` rather than string concatenation to build system-agnostic paths.

If `sendEmail` is `async`, be sure to `await` that as well.

My file structure is:

```
├── backend
│   └── views
│       ├── header.html
│       └── index.ejs
└── send-emails.js
```